# C# Trouble adding to a generic list

Tags: c#, console-application

This is a follow up question from another post but that post was answered.  I have a for loop that I want to add three items to  a generic class and I'm not sure how to do that.  How do I add those items?

```
private static void TestResults()
{
    List<Record> Records = new List<Record>();

    for (int i = 0; i < ProxyList.Count; i++)
    {
        string[] split = List[i].Split('|');
        // This is what i dont know how to do
        //  split[0] = Name, split[1] = SomeValue and split[3] = OrderNr
    }
}

class Records
{
    public static string Name { get; set; }
    public static int SomeValue { get; set; }
    public static int OrderNr { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for one thing, your properties *must not* be static. You want different data for each instance, right? So they need to be *instance* properties. Personally I'd also make the type immutable, but that's another matter:

```
class Record // Changed from Records; each object is only a single record...
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
}

private static List<Record> ConvertRecords(IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
    List<Record> records = new List<Record>();

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        string[] split = line.Split('|');
        Record record = new Record {
            Name = split[0],
            SomeValue = int.Parse(split[1]),
            OrderNumber = int.Parse(split[2]);
        };
        records.Add(record);
    }
}
```

As of C# 3 / .NET 3.5, a more idiomatic approach would be to use LINQ:

```
private static List<Record> ConvertRecords(IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
    return (from line in lines
            let split = line.Split('|')
            select new Record {
                Name = split[0],
                SomeValue = int.Parse(split[1]),
                OrderNumber = int.Parse(split[2]);
            }).ToList();
    }
}
```

... on the other hand, that's relatively advanced if you're really just starting to learn the language.

To be honest, Stack Overflow is better for asking *specific questions* than structured learning - I suggest you get hold of a good book, such as [C# 4 in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596800959).

Answer (score 4):

The first step is to associate the fields with instances of `Records` vs. the type itself.  This is done by removing the static modifier

```
class Records
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
    public int OrderNr { get; set; }
}
```

To actually create instances try the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < ProxyList.Count; i++) {
  string[] split = List[i].Split('|');
  Records record = new Records() {
    Name = split[0]
    SomeValue = Int32.Parse(split[1])
    OrderNr = Int32.Parse(split[2])
  };
  Records.add(record);
}
```

This particular example uses an object initializer to combine the acts of creating the object and settings its fields.  This could be expanded into the longer form as follows

```
for (int i = 0; i < ProxyList.Count; i++) {
  string[] split = List[i].Split('|');
  Records record = new Records();
  record.Name = split[0];
  record.SomeValue = Int32.Parse(split[1]);
  record.OrderNr = Int32.Parse(split[2]);
  Records.add(record);
}
```

The `Int32.Parse` method will throw an exception if the item in the original `string` wasn't a number.  If this is a possibility (think bad input) then you'll want to wrap the creation of `Records` with a `try / catch` statement

Comment: I would also add to change the fields in Records from static to just public <type> <name> {get;set;} since there will need to be an instantiation of this class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you use static !!! but try this :

```
private static void TestResults()
    {
List<Record> Records = new List<Record>();

for (int i = 0; i < ProxyList.Count; i++)
        {;
            string[] split = List[i].Split('|');
            Records.Add(new Record() {Name = Namesplit[0] , SomeValue = split[1], OrderNr = split[3]}) ;

        }
}
```